# Why can't I set "type 'double'" to entity "type 'double *'?"

Tags: c++, function, pointers

My function is

```
void BookRecord::getCost(double *c)
 {
 }
```

I'm supposed to copy a member variable (double m_dCost) into the variable pointed to by the function. But when I do this ...

```
void BookRecord::getCost(double *c)
 {
   c = m_dCost;
 }
```

My compiler tells me "a value of type 'double' cannot be assigned to an entity of type 'double *'." So why not? And if I can't do it that way, how do I copy the member variable into it?

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks very much!

Edit: For those saying I haven't looked up anything, let me just announce that I'm new to C++ and programming in general. Maybe I don't quite understand why double m_dCost and double *c are so different.

Comment: It's right there in the error message.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is getting up-voted. "I'm so bogged down in my brain...", really?!? The OP has not researched or checked anything. This is not a good stackoverflow question.

Comment: The OP is a full-time college student who just went through midterms. Who is also new to C++. So... take it easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c =  m_dCost;
```

it's an invalid statement...

```
c = &m_dcost;
```

is valid. Here `c` stores the memory address of `m_dcost`.

```
*c = m_dcost;
```

is also valid. It points to the variable whose memory address is stored in `c`.

Answer (score 5):

You should try this:

```
*c =  m_dCost;
```

`double` and `double *` are different type, you can't assign them directly. You need to use the **dereference(indirection) operator** `*` here.

Reference: [Dereference operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator)

Comment: That's better. haha Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

"c" is pointer pointing to a double variable, however, "m_dCost" is a double variable, you should use "*" operator to refer to the variable that "c" points to.

Just like songyuanyao's solution:

```
*c =  m_dCost;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, double and double * are different types. double is for a double-precision floating point, but any type followed by an asterisk is its own type representing a **pointer** to the typename. So, double* contains only an address to the a double variable, not the variable itself.

If what you're trying to do is to copy m_dCost into c, do this:

```
void BookRecord::getCost(double *c)
{
    *c = m_dCost; // variable that c points to <- m_dCost
}
```

But I noticed that your question is tagged with C++. If you are using C++, then you should just make a class, and that class should hide the pointers.

```
public class BookRecord
{
   public:
   BookRecord();
   double getCost();
   private:
   double _cost;
}
double BookRecord::getCost()
{
   return _cost; // Your function returns void and the "return value" is stored through a pointer
                 // Use a return statement instead for simplicity
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to follow specific guidelines (we have a mock Statement of Work) for this, so I'm not allowed to do that THIS time. But we are using classes in this program. Just not in that instance. I'm just new to all this, and I didn't quite grasp pointers in the short time we covered them, so I wasn't sure why double m_dCost and double *c were so very different.